# Мне нужно маленькое условие но не знаю как написать js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно : если число заканчиваеться на 50 (например 350 450 и т.д.) то выполняеться следующая функция.

Comment: Просто как палка `if(350%100 == 50){alert("Ваша функция");}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (value % 100 == 50) {
  следующаяФункция();
}
```